# No me reconoce validacion

Tags: java, validación

tengo este codigo pero no me reconoce

throw new ValidateServiceException("Ya existe el nombre "+usuario.getNombres());

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Usuario save(Usuario usuario) {
        try {
            UsuarioValidator.save(usuario);
            if(usuREPO.findByNombres(usuario.getNombres()) !=null) {                
                throw new ValidateServiceException("Ya existe el nombre "+usuario.getNombres());
            }
            usuario.setActivo(true);
            Usuario registro = usuREPO.save(usuario);
            return registro;
    }catch(ValidateServiceException | NoDataFoundException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage(),e);
        throw e;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        throw new GeneralServiceException(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
```

el postman me muestra "query did not return a unique result: 2"

pero en este otro si reconoce la exception y me manda el mensaje

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)

    public Usuario findById(Integer id) {
        try {
            Usuario registro =  usuREPO.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NoDataFoundException ("No existe el usuario con ese id"));
            return registro;
        }catch(ValidateServiceException | NoDataFoundException e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage(),e);
            throw e;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            throw new GeneralServiceException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
    }
```

en este si me muestra "No existe el usuario con ese id",  des ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la lógica detrás de `getNombres()`? Recuerda [edit] tu pregunta para más detalles.

Comment: Saludos padaleiana, me podrias aclara a que se refiere con la logica de getNombres(), a la entidad, al repository, me podrias ayudar, gracias

Comment: mi error estaba en que tenia dos nombres iguales en la base, al eliminar ya toma la validation de nombre unico